# Swift: How can I wait for an event and then switch the view?

Tags: ios, swift, view

Hey I'm doing a mini game application atm, which switches from one minigame view to the next one. Is there some kind of event listener in swift? If a game (SpriteKit Game) is finished it should fire an event, that its done now, and the view controller should then know, that it should switch to the next game view. I tried around with segues, but it doesn't seem to work like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I know a way, but it's not a very 'clean' way. You could add an if statement to your `update` function to check for a condition. For example a `gameOver` boolean that becomes `true` when a certain condition is met.

If it's true you can move to another scene.

```
var gameOver = false

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if gameOver {
        goToGameOverView()
    }
}

func goToGameOverView() {

    // Your code here

}
```

Maybe there's a better way, but this is the way that I know.

Comment: this doesnt work, because the SpriteKitGame has his own SpriteKitGameViewController, and the ViewController shouldnt have an update method, and not all the games are written in SpriteKit :(

Comment: i've fixed it. after i've defined a var that was connected to the controller like var controller : ChallengeController!. in the gameOver function i then simply did controller.anyFunctionFromController(params) :)